# What do +,- and ? symbols represent in `service --status-all`

Tags: ubuntu, services, upstart

What do +,- and ? symbols represent in `service --status-all` represent in Ubuntu 14.04. I am not able to understand it properly.

I guess `+` here might mean delayed services which start after the system startup.

Similarly, `-` would mean services running at startup.

No idea about the `?` symbol. Somebody please help me identifying symbols.

[image: SAMPLE_STARTUP PROCESS]

Comment: `initctl list` might be a better command to view an overview of the services on your system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the `/usr/sbin/service` file script

```
#printf " %s %-60s %s\n" "[?]" "$SERVICE:" "unknown" 1>&2
#printf " %s %-60s %s\n" "[+]" "$SERVICE:" "running"
#printf " %s %-60s %s\n" "[-]" "$SERVICE:" "NOT running"

[?] means the service status isn't known (the init file does not output a status)
[+] means the service is running
[-] means the service is not running
```

Edit, this was also answered here:

- [How do interpret the output of 'service --status-all'](https://superuser.com/questions/367863/how-do-interpret-the-output-of-service-status-all)

Answer (score 1):

The status is [ + ] for running services, [ - ] for stopped services and [ ? ] for services without a status command.

Comment: The existing answer already covers this point, and there is no value-addition in your answer. You may like to delete your answer (which doesn't serve any purpose IMHO)!